# How to handle high values/low values in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using power exchange to read/write mainframe files through listeners, is it possible to handle low values/high values present in mainframe files through informatica ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: High values/low values are invisible characters in mainframe, whose HEXI equivalent is x'FF' and x'00' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I once had problem handling low values present in a mainframe file. I had used the replacechr function in an expression to replace the those characters with space. I think the low values correspond to an ascii value of 0.